# Terminal: get 16-colors default color scheme in 256color mode

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors

I really really like the default (dark) color scheme in 16 colors terminal/tty emacs (`TERM=xterm`), but with some plugins like powerline, 16 colors doesn't cut it.

Hence I need to switch to 256colors (`TERM=xterm-256color`).

The thing is, all the default colors get really ugly in 256 colors, not only when editing c/c++ source files but also in the minibuffer, when selecting regions etc...

Does anybody have a link to a theme or a piece of code to get the good old 8 colors scheme back in 256 colors ?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody have a link to a theme...

[Solarized theme](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized) has options for lower terminal colors and degrade from 256 colors. Perhaps you can tweak that.